# Number of functions to receive 2 values

Tags: combinatorics, functions

I have a set $A$ with $5$ items: $1,2,3,4,5$

I want to know how many functions are there that make $|f[A]|=2$ if $f: A->A$

So what I thought is that it's the same like to put $5$ balls in $2$ boxes out of $5$ boxes.
My direction to the solution would be: choose $2$ boxes out of the $5$ boxes and put the $5$ balls in the two boxes so you have at least one ball in each box.

So there are $10$ ways to choose the two boxes out of $5$, and $D(2,5-2)$ ways to put the $5$ balls in the $2$ boxes.

So $10\cdot4 = 40$

However, this is not the solution. What am I missing?

Comment: You're probably treating the balls as indistinguishable, which does not fit the original problem.

Comment: @Stefan How would I change my solution to correct it to this case?

Comment: As Ross described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having chosen the two elements in the image of $f$, you have to assign one of the two as the function value for each element of $A$.  There are $2$ ways to assign each one, so there are $2^5$ ways to make the assignment.  We require that at least one element go to each value, and $2$ of the possible assignments take all five elements to the same value, so there are $30$ ways to assign the values of $f$.  The total number of functions is then $10 \cdot 30=300$